# Searching by Time - MongoDB / NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have a document with the following time:

```
 "time" : ISODate("2013-12-31T03:00:00Z")
```

I'm currently trying to find this document using a MongoDB query with the Node.JS driver.

```
var time = new Date(2013,11,31,3,0,0,0);
```

This Date prints out as follows using console.log()

```
Tue Dec 31 2013 03:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST)
```

When I try to find this document using the standard collection.findOne (I'm positive the query itself isn't the problem, rather the timestamp), it doesn't find the document. The Mongo shell shows the document exists. How have I formatted my time incorrectly?

EDIT:
I'll add in the query too.

```
collection.findOne(
        {
         "time" : time},
        {"_id" : 0},
        function(err, items){
            if (err){
                throw err;
            }
            console.log(err);
            console.log(items);
            res.send(items);
    });
```

Comment: what is the value of time in your query and if you are searching on time why are you passing _id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a time zone problem. The timestamp you're looking for is `2013-12-31T03:00:00Z`, the trailing `Z` means "zero time zone offset". But the version of `new Date` that you're using:

```
var time = new Date(2013,11,31,3,0,0,0);
```

interprets all those values in the current time zone. If we look at your `console.log` output:

```
Tue Dec 31 2013 03:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST)
```

we can see that you're in the EST time zone and that your `time` is `03:00` in EST rather that `03:00` in UTC.

Probably the easiest thing to do is to use [`Date.UTC`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC) to convert your components to UTC before creating your `Date` instance:

```
var time = new Date(Date.UTC(2013,11,31,3,0,0,0));
```

Now you should have `2013-12-31T03:00:00Z` in your `time` and your query should work better.